# 2 HP Officejet conflicting, one keeps disappearing from Devices and Printers

Tags: printer

I have 2 HP OfficeJet printers, one is the 8100 Pro and the other is the 7740 Pro, both work perfectly. However only one remains fully installed at any time.

If I install the 8100 first and then the 7740, both appear on my Devices and Printers, but eventually the first one will disappear (the 8100). If I do the same in reverse orther, both appear and work, but eventually the first one (now the 7740) will disappear. I'm a bit tired of reinstalling over and over. I'm running Windows 10 pro x64. I've tried the original drivers and the online drivers, no luck. I'm aware this is one of many common issues with HP Officejet printers vanishing, but still no luck solving it.

In the past both vanished while using Windows 8.1 Things got a bit better, now only one vanishes. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 8100 at least and likely the 7740 have built in Ethernet cards and maybe Wireless as well.

Give both printers Static IP addresses on your network.

It appeared from your post that you just set them up and DHCP is default. When the printer address changes, the local printer driver loses the connection.

Use the Printer control panel, Networking section and give the printers Static IP addresses.

I do this and my HP 8600 never loses its bearings.

You may need to just refresh the driver install when you change the printer networking.

Comment: Thanks John, yes, the 8100 and 7740 both have Ethernet cards (and Wireless), I currently have Wifi OFF, so the printers are connected via Ethernet cable to my router, and my laptop directly to the router also via Ethernet, so no wireless at all.

I just finished setting both to use FIXED/Static IP addresses as you suggested, I will update this question in a few weeks to see how it works because at least in my experience the vanishing doesn't happen right away, so to avoid reporting it works and then it doesn't, I will wait. Thanks for the time and explanation.

Comment: So just set the Printer Network Settings for the Ethernet properties to Static IP to ensure the correct addressing at all times.

Comment: Updating: thanks John, it works.